# finding index for a specific number in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of numbers, i'm supposed to find the largest number in that list and output its index, not the actual value.
the list is called numbers.
this is what i have:

```
N = 0
for i in numbers:
    if i > N:
            N=i
for N in numbers:
    print (numbers.index[N])
```

this returns this error
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
I would prefer not use the 'max' function.
the code will return the largest number, how do i get it to return the index?

Comment: is this a homework problem? Maybe instead of iterating over the values of the list, you might try indexing into the list. Something like `range(0,len(numbers))`

Comment: tried that already, and yes it is homework i meant to put that in the question but it slipped my mind.

Comment: code is almost correct, but need to adjust the indentation. `N` holds the max value, so no need to iterate the list again, remove the second `for`-loop, use `print (numbers.index(N))`

Answer (score 1):

I think this code will be helpful to you.

```
index = 0
length = len(numbers)
maxNum = 0
for i in range(length):
    if numbers[i] > maxNum:
        index = i
        maxNum = numbers[i]
```

The index is what you want.